# How to do a pattern range match that is multi-line and non-greedy?

Tags: regex, bash

I am trying to pull a bash one-liner for printing lines between two patterns. I need it to be non-greedy, though. I have a file 'test.txt' that contains the following:

```
############ Apple ############
# 1
# 2
# 3
# 4      
#################################

############ Orange ############
# 1
# 2
# 3
# 4
#################################

############ Grape ############
# 1
# 2
# 3
# 4      
#################################
```

What I want to be printed is the "Orange" section. And ONLY that section. That is, I want the following printed:

```
############ Orange ############
# 1
# 2
# 3
# 4
#################################
```

I also do not want to match for a specific number of lines, as the line count will fluctuate. I have tried a bunch of different things. I have tried sed, awk, grep (with -P and *.? regex). Nothing seems to fit the bill here. Sed and awk are greedy, so I can't match the end of the section. Grep (as far as I can tell) doesn't support multi-line range matching. Is there a solution to this using built-ins? I know that there is pcregrep, but I'd rather use built-ins or something that "ships" with common distros. I'm going for "out-of-the-box" and elegant. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an address range with [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
sed -n '/^#\+[ ]*Orange[ ]*#\+/,/^#\+$/ p' infile
```

It yields:

```
############ Orange ############
# 1
# 2
# 3
# 4
#################################
```

Comment: Thanks. Modified your answer down to this: `sed -n '/orange/I,/##/p'`

Answer (score 3):

```
perl -ne 'BEGIN{$/=/^#+$/} print $_ if /Orange/' file
```

Comment: This works, but I wound up doing it like this: `sed -n '/orange/I,/##/p'`